# Proguard turning variables to private?

Tags: java, obfuscation

I have obfuscated my application today, and for some random reason, Proguard renames one of my public static variables to private, while I need the variable to be public, so I can access it using Javascript to applet.

I decided to decompile the client, and change it to public manually, but after compilation I get 100+ errors.

Why is it happening?

Why does ProGuard renames some variables to private, is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning `allowaccessmodification` off?

You could also try this in your config:

```
-keepclassmembers class yourClass {
    public static int myInt;
```